# How can I set the global value of a symbol created from a string?

Tags: hooks, symbols

I'm trying to make this little convenience function work:

```
(defun my-make-hook (when procedure)
     (let ((hook-symbol (intern (concat
                                 (substring (symbol-name when) 1)
                                 "-"
                                 (symbol-name procedure)
                                 "-hook"))))
       (unless (boundp hook-symbol)
         (set hook-symbol nil)
         (advice-add procedure when (lambda (&rest _) (run-hooks hook-symbol)))
         hook-symbol)))
```

But I'm getting an error that the interned symbol is void, and I believe I may actually be somehow setting the value of the symbol `hook-symbol` itself, rather than the symbol that `hook-symbol` evaluates to.

EDIT: I'm calling it with, e.g., (my-make-hook :after 'load-theme).

Comment: When are you getting that error? How are you calling `my-make-hook`?

Comment: What @Stefan said. Alternatively, use `(lambda (&rest _) (run-hooks ',hook-symbol)). (That's a backquote before the lambda.)

Comment: Better not create any `around-load-theme-hook`s.

Comment: @Drew, would that _replace_ `hook-symbol` in the lambda with the newly created symbol (say, `after-load-theme-hook`) instead of making the lambda refer to the lexical variable `hook-symbol`?

Comment: @politza, good call. So far my use cases have been `:before` and `:after`. I haven't used any abnormal hooks. My original code threw an error if `when` wasn't `:before` or `:after`, but I omitted that to make the procedure more clear.

Comment: Correct. If all you need is the value then it is OK. If you need the variable *as a variable* (e.g. to be able to change its value or access its other properties (e.g. plist) then it is not adequate. If you need it *as a variable* then you need lexical scoping. Also, doing it as I suggested, the lambda form is a *list* that gets evaluated. It is not byte-compiled, for example, because it is not known at compile-time to be code - it's just a list then.

Comment: Maybe use a macro for this ? May use `defvar` and document the hook.

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide the symbol in the way `defvar` desires (that is, not quoted but also not unquoted/evaluated). But that's probably another question.

Answer (score 1):

My crystal ball says that the above code is written in a file that does not have the magic cookie `-*- lexical-binding:t -*-`, and hence the let-binding of `hook-symbol` is dynamic rather than lexical, and by the time the advice is run, that variable doesn't exist any more, so you get a void-variable error.

Hence: place `;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-` on the first line of the file in which you wrote your function, then re-load the file, and that should hopefully fix it.

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan. I was only considering that `(set hook-symbol nil)` is evaluated inside the `let` form, and forgot that the lambda needs to refer back to the local variables.

Comment: For whatever reason `after-load-theme-hook` still isn't working, but with lexical binding the procedure works perfectly for all my other hooks.

Comment: You might like to post another question for that `after-load-them-hook` case, where you can give more details about "isn't working".  Maybe the problem is simply that the `load-theme` function signals an error, so it never ends up running the "after" part.  Or maybe `advice-add` is called after the `load-theme` function is called.

Comment: It seems that setting `lexical-binding` to `t` makes the hook work, but only in the _buffer_ where it was created.